# laravel eloquent create new record without repeat new keyword before save() method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I wrote this code in Laravel:

```
    $setting = new Setting;
    $setting->name = 'name1';
    $setting->save();
    
    $setting->name = 'name2';
    $setting->save();
```

after executing I see just `name2` in the database
but after I execute this code:

```
    $setting = new Setting;
    $setting->name = 'name1';
    $setting->save();
    $setting = new Setting;
    $setting->name = 'name2';
    $setting->save();
```

both the records saved correctly, so I have `name1` and `name2`.

I can't understand why reassigning `$setting` variable with `$setting = new Setting;` is so important?

the type of `$setting` is `object of Setting` why should we reassign it again? how does it help?

how does it work? why the first snipped doesn't work?

for example in this PHP snippet:

```
<?php 
class Foo{
    public $name;
    public function bar(){
        echo $this->name;
    }
}
$obj1 = new Foo;
$obj1->name = 'object_one';
$obj1->bar();
//////$obj1 = new Foo;// we don't need this line in this snippet 
$obj1->name = 'object_two';
$obj1->bar();
var_dump($obj1); // answer is object(Foo)#1
```

It seems Laravel works with the `object unique id`... where is the related code in Laravel? where Laravel is checking the id of the object to understand it should run the `create` or the `update` method?

Comment: It’s important, because without reassigning `$setting = new Setting`, you’re modifying the same record, not creating a new one. Note the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `create()` if you have `'name'` inside the `Setting`'s `$fillable` property.

```php
Setting::create(['name' => 'name1']);
Setting::create(['name' => 'name2']);
```

The reason you need to reassign it in your code is because `$setting` gets bound to the `Setting` model. If you don't reassign it, then any operation you make results in an update instead of inserting a new setting.

Here's a table to illustrate:

| code | `$setting` |
| --- | --- |
| ``` $setting = new Setting; ``` | ``` Setting#1{} ``` |
| ``` $setting->name = 'name1'; ``` | ``` Setting#1{ +name: 'name1' } ``` |
| ``` $setting->save(); ``` | ``` Setting#1{ +id: 1 +name: 'name1' +created_at: '2021-03-19 20:00:00' +updated_at: '2021-03-19 20:00:00' } ``` |
| ``` $setting->name = 'name2'; ``` | ``` Setting#1{ +id: 1 +name: 'name2' +created_at: '2021-03-19 20:00:00' +updated_at: '2021-03-19 20:00:00' } ``` |
| ``` $setting->save(); ``` | ``` Setting#1{ +id: 1 +name: 'name2' +created_at: '2021-03-19 20:00:00' +updated_at: '2021-03-19 20:00:05' } ``` |
| ``` $setting = new Setting; ``` | ``` Setting#2{} ``` |
| ``` $setting->name = 'name3'; ``` | ``` Setting#2{ +name: 'name3' } ``` |
| ``` $setting->save(); ``` | ``` Setting#2{ +id: 2 +name: 'name3' +created_at: '2021-03-19 20:00:20' +updated_at: '2021-03-19 20:00:20' } ``` |